# Inserting the data in a session and reading it back in the same session

Tags: hibernate, plsql

So here is my problem I have 2 tables A and B. I have started a session in hibernate and i am saving the data to table a after that i am trying to copy the data from table A to table B using Stored Proc(Called in same session), then commit. but Stored proc is not able to find the data in table A why so ?.
I think within same session data should be available, even before commit ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit your save to A so that the stored proc of the DB can see the data in A and copy it to B.

While you do not commit, no change is seen in the DB.

Comment: The stored proc is executed by the DB, and the DB does not see your uncommitted changes.